Nextjs 15- Type error: Type '{ __tag__: "GET"; __param_position__: "second"; __param_type__:
Linting and checking validity of types  ..next/types/app/api/news-upload/[slug]/route.ts:49:7
Type error: Type '{ tag: "GET"; param_position: "second"; param_type: { params: Params; }; }' does not satisfy the constraint 'ParamCheck'.
The types of 'param_type.params' are incompatible between these types.
Type 'Params' is missing the following properties from type 'Promise': then, catch, finally, [Symbol.toStringTag]
47 |     Diff<
48 |       ParamCheck,

49 |       {
|       ^
50 |         tag: 'GET'
51 |         param_position: 'second'
52 |         param_type: SecondArg<MaybeField<TEntry, 'GET'>>
PS D:\websolution\summit>

